# How can we number tuples of query retrieval?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to give a rank to a sorted query output. How can I do that?

Comment: I used rank() function, but it didn't work. I queried in mysql.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention *which* database you're using, but most of them support window functions like `row_number()` which let you do this.

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY foo)
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY foo;
```

(Or `rank()`, or `dense_rank()`. They all behave differently in case of ties in the ordering term).

Or, of course, you can just increment a counter for each row you retrieve in the program that's executing the query.

```
rn = 0
for each row in results
  rn += 1
  do_something()
```